# PHP Convert string into timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm working with a web service that is doing an HTTP GET request to my server and sending the timestamp value as follows:

```
timeStamp=Mon+Jul+13+10%3A52%3A00+EST+2015
```

I then need to covert this into a timestamp I can insert into my database, but I'm having trouble extracting a valid value. I've tried using strtotime, e.g.:

```
echo(strtotime('Mon+Jul+13+10%3A52%3A00+EST+2015') );
```

but that doesn't return anything. The timestamp in this example is July 13th, 2015 at 10:52:00.

Looking for a solution to converting this string into a valid timestamp.

Comment: start with urldecode()

Comment: That's a rather odd time format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. You have received a urlencoded string, so you need to reverse this first.

**[FIDDLE](http://viper-7.com/priZ6L)**

```
<?php
$timeStamp="Mon+Jul+13+10%3A52%3A00+EST+2015";
$timeStamp=urldecode($timeStamp); 
echo strtotime($timeStamp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the "+" and "%3A" with a " " (space) and ":"

```
$good = array(' ', ':');
$bad = array ('+', '%3A');

echo str_replace($bad, $good, 'Mon+Jul+13+10%3A52%3A00+EST+2015');
```

Or if you want the numerical time, change the last line to this:

```
echo strtotime(str_replace($bad, $good, 'Mon+Jul+13+10%3A52%3A00+EST+2015'));
```